# podman machine init fails with unhelpful output

Tags: github-actions, podman

I am running the command

```
podman machine init
```

in the `/entrypoint.sh` script which I reference in my Dockerfile:

```
# Container image that runs your code
FROM ubuntu:latest

# Copies your code file from your action repository to the filesystem path `/` of the container
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y git gcc python3-dev musl-dev libffi-dev podman
# Code file to execute when the docker container starts up (`entrypoint.sh`)
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

The `Dockerfile` and the `entrypoint.sh` scripts are in my github repo where I have github actions configured.  The problem I see my my log output from the Github action is this ...

```
2022-11-29T04:56:58.6855699Z + podman machine init
2022-11-29T04:56:59.1867174Z Downloading VM image: fedora-coreos-37.20221106.2.1-qemu.x8…
2022-11-29T04:56:59.3660034Z [1A[JDownloading VM image: fedora-coreos-37.20221106.2.1-qemu.x8…
...
2022-11-29T04:57:06.5082410Z [1A[JDownloading VM image: fedora-coreos-37.20221106.2.1-qemu.x8…
2022-11-29T04:57:06.9133659Z Extracting compressed file
2022-11-29T04:57:36.0586753Z Error: exit status 1
```

Extracting compressed file?  Did I run out of disk space? What?  I am not even sure where to begin to debug this.

Comment: You're trying to run `podman machine init` *inside* your docker container? So you want a VM inside a container and then run more containers inside that VM? I'm not sure that makes any sense.

Comment: AAARGGGG!!!!! *BONK* *BONK* (That is me hitting my head on the desk).  Thanks